# WordPress pagina de conteúdo, como editar

Tags: wordpress

Quero mudar a página que exibe os conteúdo quando clica em um post, a matéria em si.
Quero colocar nessa página um bloco de anúncios do Google Adwords e colocar uma `<div>` e um bloco PHP.

Qual página .php devo editar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

single.php é a página que você esta procurando